# How to update a record with literal percent literal (%) in PostgreSQL without saving it as "\%"

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, escaping, railo, cfml

I need to update a record, which contains literal percent signs, using PostgreSQL in Railo. The query looks like

```
<cfquery>
update foo set bar = 'string with % in it %'
</cfQuery>
```

It throws error as ColdFusion normally interprets it as a wildcard character. I can escape it using the following query.

```
<cfquery>
update foo set bar = 'string with escaped \% in it \%'
</cfQuery>
```

However, the record now contains "\%" in the database and will be displayed on the page as "\%".

I found a [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html) with an example of escaping percent sign in a SELECT. But it does not work for me: syntax error at or near "ESCAPE".

```
SELECT emp_discount 
FROM Benefits 
WHERE emp_discount LIKE '10\%'  
ESCAPE '\';
```

Is there a better to achieve the same goal? The underlining database is PostgreSQL. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation you are linking to is for QoQ - there's no guarantee of it being the same syntax for PostgreSQL. Also `%` should only be a wildcard when used with `LIKE` - what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Shouldn't you escape % with \% instead of /% ?

Comment: Are you running a db query or a QoQ? Also, are you using `cfqueryparam` in your real code? If not, try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queryparameters escape special characters.  Yet another reason to use them.

Comment: The use of <cfqueryparam value="#foo#" CFSQLTYPE='CF_SQL_CHAR'> totally does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Is your database column `char`? I am not familiar with the data type mappings for postgresql.

Comment: Good question. the database column is text in postgresql. I can't find the mapping from coldfusion to postgresql. It seems both CF_SQL_CHAR and CF_SQL_VARCHAR do the same thing in my situation.

Comment: I cannot find an official reference, but [this thread](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/TEXT-columns-should-indentify-as-java-sql-Types-CLOB-td2636468.html) suggests `cf_sql_varchar` or even `cf_sql_longvarchar` may be the right type. `char` is typically used for fixed length (not variable) fields. Though from what I have read the `text` type sounds a lot like a `clob`. So it is possible that would work too.

Comment: Fail how? [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13709541/edit) to include the exact code, values and error message thrown